# Filter with like in BigQuery where the pattern are in an array

Tags: google-bigquery, filtering, sql-like

I would like to filter a column in bigquery where the `LIKE` should match multiple patterns. Something like:

```
SELECT description
FROM mytable
WHERE 
    mycol LIKE "%window%"
    OR mycol LIKE "%door%"
    OR mycol LIKE "%carpet%"
```

but I would like it to be

```
SELECT description
FROM mytable
WHERE 
    mycol LIKE IN ["%window%", "%door%", "%carpet%"]
```

Ideally the patterns `("window", "door", "carpet",...)` are stored in another table (so they are dynamically generated).

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for [Quantified Like Operator.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#like_operator_quantified)

See sample here using `LIKE ANY`:

```
WITH Words AS
 (SELECT 'Intend with clarity.' as value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Secure with intention.' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Clarity and security.')
SELECT * FROM Words WHERE value LIKE ANY ('Intend%', '%intention%');
```

```
/*------------------------+
 | value                  |
 +------------------------+
 | Intend with clarity.   |
 | Secure with intention. |
 +------------------------*/
```